# In R - datasauRus Package Unexpected Error Message

Tags: r

I am learning R using the `datasauRus` package and keep getting an error message although I have followed a tutorial exactly - I think .. haha

Doing all code in Posit Cloud.

I tried the following:

```
install.packages ('datasauRus') 
library('datasauRus')
```

When I run this command, as per a tutorial I am following, I see an error message:

```
ggplot (datasaurus_dozen, aes = (x=x, y=y, colour = dataset))+
    geom_point()+
    theme_void()+
    theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
    facet_wrap(~dataset,ncol=3))
```

Error message:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "ggplot (datasaurus_dozen, aes = (x=x,"
```

Answer (score 1):

`aes()` is a function that is provided to the argument `mapping`. A correct way to do it would be:

```
ggplot (datasaurus_dozen, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, colour = dataset)) +
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know datasauRus, but the ggplot code has a clear error: there should NOT be an equals sign between the "aes" and the material in the parentheses.  And the facet_wrap() command has an extra close parenthesis at the end

E.g., the code should read:

```
ggplot (datasaurus_dozen, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = dataset))+geom_point()+theme_void()+theme(legend.position = "none")+ facet_wrap(~dataset,ncol=3)
```

Or, alternatively

```
ggplot (datasaurus_dozen, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, colour = dataset))+geom_point()+theme_void()+theme(legend.position = "none")+ facet_wrap(~dataset,ncol=3)
```